# Another passing variable through function jQuery/JS problem

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```
function mouseOver(variable)
{
    return function()
    {
        $(variable).fadeIn(100);
    };
}

function mouseOut(variable)
{
    return function()
    {
        $(variable).fadeOut(100);
    };
}

function lawyer(var1, var2, var3, var4)
{
    return function()
    {
        $(var1).bind('mouseenter', mouseOver(var2)).bind('mouseleave', mouseOut(var2)).click(
        function()
        {
            $(var1).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
            $(var1).removeClass('off').addClass('on');

            $(var3).bind('mouseenter', mouseOver(var4)).bind('mouseleave', mouseOut(var4));
            $(var3).removeClass('on').addClass('off');

            $(var4).hide();
        });
    }
}

lawyer("#group", ".b", "#group2", ".l");
```

What would be the reason for this not working?

It works in that it hides $(var4).hide();, but clicking on the object doesn't seem to do anything. It works if I take the code out of a function and just copy/paste it a few times and change the targets.
I'm not seeing it... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try adding an execution operator at the end of the `lawyer` call: `lawyer("#group", ".b", "#group2", ".l")();` Or just don't have `lawyer()` return a function by unwrapping the code from the function returned.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Both of those solutions worked, but I just unwrapped my code from the function return. Not sure why I was doing that. But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear to me why you're returning a new function from `lawyer()`. Your call to `lawyer(...)` does not execute the returned function. Could that be the reason?

One technique I use often to determine whether some particular bit of code is even being run at all, is to insert an `alert("hi")` or something in there. If you don't see the alert, the code isn't being run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function lawyer(var1, var2, var3, var4) {
    return function() {
        $(var1)
            .bind('mouseenter', function() { mouseOver(var2); })
            .bind('mouseleave', function() { mouseOut(var2); })
            .click(function() {
                $(var1).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
                $(var1).removeClass('off').addClass('on');

                $(var3).
                    bind('mouseenter', function() { mouseOver(var4) })
                    .bind('mouseleave', function() { mouseOut(var4) });
                $(var3).removeClass('on').addClass('off');

                $(var4).hide();
            });
    }
};

lawyer("#group", ".b", "#group2", ".l")();
```